# How to import records of 2 parent objects and a junction object inbetween them using Data:Tree in SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, json, data-export, junction-object, data-import

I created some test data in a scratch org for a Trailhead project and i wanted to try to export it and then import it into my Devhub. I ran three different export queries and then created my own plan .json file to bring them all together for the import. However when the import ran, it created all my records in triplicate about a minute apart. Any ideas why this might have happened?

Here's my plan.json:

```
[
    {
        "sobject": "Session__c",
        "saveRefs": true,
        "resolveRefs": false,
        "files": [
            "sessions-data-Session__cs.json"
        ]
    },
    {
        "sobject": "Speaker__c",
        "saveRefs": true,
        "resolveRefs": false,
        "files": [
            "speakers-data-Speaker__cs.json"
        ]
    },
    {
        "sobject": "Session_Speaker__c",
        "saveRefs": true,
        "resolveRefs": true,
        "files": [
            "session-speaker-data-Session_Speaker__c.json"
        ]
    }
]
```

My Session__c.json:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Session__c",
                "referenceId": "Session__cRef1"
            },
            "Name": "What We Can Learn From the Greatest Tennis Players",
            "Session_Date__c": "2020-02-11T20:00:00.000+0000",
            "Level__c": "Beginner",
            "Description__c": "A look at history's greatest players and their strategies to get ahead."
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Session__c",
                "referenceId": "Session__cRef2"
            },
            "Name": "Nootropics Use In C-Suite Roles",
            "Session_Date__c": "2020-02-07T20:00:00.000+0000",
            "Level__c": "Intermediate",
            "Description__c": "Learn about what executives today are taking to help them improve their cognitive performance!"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Session__c",
                "referenceId": "Session__cRef3"
            },
            "Name": "Salesforce DX and Lightning Web Components",
            "Session_Date__c": "2020-02-04T20:00:00.000+0000",
            "Level__c": "Intermediate",
            "Description__c": "LWCs are here to stay. Learn how to go from beginner to a well versed developer with this new framework."
        }
    ]
}
```

My Speaker__c.json:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Speaker__c",
                "referenceId": "Speaker__cRef1"
            },
            "Email__c": "jmm72011@gmail.com",
            "Bio__c": "Jorge is an experienced speaker. He's led many sessions at DreamForce!",
            "First_Name__c": "Jorge",
            "Last_Name__c": "Mejia"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Speaker__c",
                "referenceId": "Speaker__cRef2"
            },
            "Email__c": "jwayne@email.com",
            "Bio__c": "Greatest Tennis Player at ETA. Knowledgeable about Sports.",
            "First_Name__c": "John",
            "Last_Name__c": "Wayne"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Speaker__c",
                "referenceId": "Speaker__cRef3"
            },
            "Email__c": "hali@email.com",
            "Bio__c": "Best public speaker of the 21st Century. Knowledgeable in just about every subject.",
            "First_Name__c": "Hal",
            "Last_Name__c": "Incandeza"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my Session_Speaker__c.json (Junction):

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Session_Speaker__c",
                "referenceId": "Session_Speaker__cRef1"
            },
            "Speaker__c": "@Speaker__cRef2",
            "Session__c": "@Session__cRef1"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Session_Speaker__c",
                "referenceId": "Session_Speaker__cRef2"
            },
            "Speaker__c": "@Speaker__cRef3",
            "Session__c": "@Session__cRef2"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Session_Speaker__c",
                "referenceId": "Session_Speaker__cRef3"
            },
            "Speaker__c": "@Speaker__cRef1",
            "Session__c": "@Session__cRef3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: for some reason the two parent objects (Session__c and Speaker__c) have data files that end in something like Session__cs.json. Not sure what the '__cs.json' means and if it has something to do with the behavior I'm seeing.

Any help is appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Update, I created a new scratch org and tried again. This time i changed the 'saveRefs' property to false for my junction object and i dont see any duplicates. I'm not sure how this could have made a difference. Might have been a server error ?

Comment: How did you run the queries so you get the reference into the junction object? when i run the queries into the child object im not getting the field since it's not finding the reference in the same export command